# PHPUnit Different return values every call of mocked method

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

For example I have a mocked Class like below:

```
$mock= $this->getMockBuilder("SomeClass")->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$mock->expects($this->any())
     ->method("someMethod")
     ->will($this->returnValue("RETURN VALUE"));
```

The only param of `someMethod` is an array `$arr`.

What I want to do is to return `$arr[0]` when `someMethod` is called for the first time, `$arr[1]` for the second time and so on.

The size of `$arr` is dynamic.

Any idea how to achieve this if this is even possible?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
$mock->expects($this->any())
    ->method("someMethod")
    ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(1, 2, 3));
```

With onConsecutiveCalls you can set a return value for every call of someMethod. The first call returns 1. The second call 2. The third call 3.

Comment: I've read about this but can I use this based on the argument for that mocked method? For example, ...$this->onConsecutiveCalls($arg[0], $arg[1], $arg[2])...? EDIT: I actually tried looking for a workaround but no luck so far.

Comment: You can use $arg array used in your test case. Isn't someMethod's behaviour like an iterator?

Comment: Yeah precisely, like an iterator. :)
But the problem is, I don't know what $arg array is all the time because someMethod is not called by the test itself. It's like I want to test "someBiggerMethod" and I am mocking "someMethod" called inside that function for easier testing.

Comment: Try returnCallback or returnValueMap

Comment: jepp, those two are also possible solutions, especially when no order is important. Actually tests shouldn't check an order of values.