# How to return different values from mock object depending on parameter

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, closures

I want to mock the return values of a redis server. Depending on the key I need to get back different fake values.
Since this would be still easy I want as a return value the content of a file on my hard disk, so I can vary the mock with different fake input. This is for testing a custom authentication to create different complex user rights.

I am cuurently using phpunit 9 and will upgrade soon to phphunit 10 so I want to avoid deprecated methods like `at` or `withConsecutive`.

I think a callBack function should be able to achieve that, but I just don't seem to get it right.

```php
    private function mockAuthRedisService(
        string $authFile = 'auth_admin',
        string $userGlobalsFile = 'user_globals_admin'
    ): MockObject|AuthRedisServiceInterface {
        $authJson = $this->readfile($authFile);
        $userGlobalsJson = $this->readfile($userGlobalsFile);

        $redisService = $this->getMockBuilder(AuthRedisServiceInterface::class)
                             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                             ->getMock();


        $redisService->expects($this->any())
         ->method('getAuthData')
            ->will(
                $this->returnCallback(
                    function(string $keyName) {
                        if (strstr($keyName, 'authInfo')) return $authJson;
                        if (strstr($keyName, 'userGlobals')) return $userGlobalsJson;
                    }
                )
            );

        return $redisService;
    }



    private function readfile(string $name): string
    {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/Unit/Security/test_data_files/' . $name . '.json';

        return file_get_contents($path);
    }
```

So for authentication I need to read two different files from my "redis server" and both hat a complex json structure, which is the reason I read them from disk.

Depending on different tests I want to use different input files.

So in real use I call the method "getAuthData" with different strings and depending on the strings I get different data back.

How can I achieve the flexibility of mocking with different input files?

The current setup gives me `TypeError: Mock_AuthRedisServiceInterface_4131c2db::getAuthData(): Return value must be of type string, null returned`
Which is not surprising since the two variables containing the file content are not with in the callBack function and I need an idea how the data of those two variable is available within the callBack function or an alternative solution.

I already looked at these questions:

[1][PHPunit mocking object and response differently with consecutive calls depending the object property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694606/phpunit-mocking-object-and-response-differently-with-consecutive-calls-depending)

[2][PHPUnit Different return values every call of mocked method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21542838/phpunit-different-return-values-every-call-of-mocked-method)

[3][How can I get PHPUnit MockObjects to return different values based on a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277914/how-can-i-get-phpunit-mockobjects-to-return-different-values-based-on-a-paramete?rq=2)
and some other and tried to adapt the solutions, but it didn't fit for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What I did now was the following and it is only possible because I know in which order the data is needed. So it isn't really a solution for the general problem I am just lucky that it works for me.
The code is this:

```php
    private function mockAuthRedisService(
        string $authFile = 'auth_admin',
        string $userGlobalsFile = 'user_globals_admin'
    ): MockObject|AuthRedisServiceInterface {
        $authJson = $this->readfile($authFile);
        $userGlobalsJson = $this->readfile($userGlobalsFile);

        $redisService = $this->getMockBuilder(AuthRedisServiceInterface::class)
                             ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                             ->getMock();

        $redisService->expects($this->exactly(3))
                     ->method('getAuthData')
                     ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls($authJson, $authJson, $userGlobalsJson));

        return $redisService;
    }

    private function readfile(string $name): string
    {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/Unit/Security/acs_answers/' . $name . '.json';

        return file_get_contents($path);
    }
```

So I just tell the code give me back $authJson on the first two calls and $userGlobalsJson on the third. Not the flexibility I wanted, so if any one has a better idea it is still welcome!